# How to display contents on separate lines in css in mobile/tablet view?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

I am working on a Wordpress (built on custom theme) [website](http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/) in which I want to display content on separate lines in mobile view.

The snippets of **HTML** code which I see on inspect for some content of the above website is:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="gv-table-view gv-table-container gv-table-multiple-container gv-container gv-container-2777">
    <table class="gv-table-view">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="gv-field-6-29" class="gv-field-6-29"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=29&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-sort-asc"></a>&nbsp;Year Submitted</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-1" class="gv-field-6-1"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=1&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Descriptive Title of Proposal:</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-31" class="gv-field-6-31"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=31&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Name of Institution</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-25" class="gv-field-6-25"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=25&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Awarded</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="alt">
                <td id="gv-field-6-29" class="gv-field-6-29">2015</td>
                <td id="gv-field-6-1" class="gv-field-6-1"><a href="http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/entry/4504/?gvid=2777">Creation of PRODIGE, a project management software</a>
                </td>
                <td id="gv-field-6-31" class="gv-field-6-31">Université de Montréal</td>
                <td id="gv-field-6-25" class="gv-field-6-25">3rd prize (Open Category)</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th id="gv-field-6-29" class="gv-field-6-29"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=29&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-sort-asc"></a>&nbsp;Year Submitted</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-1" class="gv-field-6-1"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=1&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Descriptive Title of Proposal:</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-31" class="gv-field-6-31"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=31&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Name of Institution</span>
                </th>
                <th id="gv-field-6-25" class="gv-field-6-25"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/?sort=25&amp;dir=asc" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Awarded</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle for the above code https://jsfiddle.net/9xsyd8hf/embedded/result

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I need to add in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xsyd8hf/embedded/result) so that I when the see the fiddle in the mobile view, it should look like this:

[image]

In the current [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xsyd8hf/embedded/result), everything is present in table format. I am wondering what changes I should make in the css so that in the mobile view everything should come in separate lines.

Comment: Do you have to use a table?

Comment: @EliyaCohen I think, I can't make any changes in the current html because that's all coming from inspect in wordpress and we are using a custom theme. Here is the [website](http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the smaller width you can display table cells as a div's. Then they will behave as you want it to behave. Then you can add additional text by CSS, or add span element and show them only on mobile views.

CSS I wrote:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {

th {
  display: none;
}

td {
  display: block;
}

td:first-child::before {
  content: 'Year Submitted';
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

}
```

And link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ms4c65/

Comment: It looks good but did you hide something ? It doesn't looks exactly the same as mock.

Comment: I just wrote a little part for you to see how you can achieve it ;) You can use for the next heading `nth-child` selector.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. It looks good. Also, in your fiddle I have added `.gv-container-2777` class so that it doesn't have the whole website which has th. Here is the fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/t9ms4c65/4/   Let me know if it is the right way to do that.

Comment: It is okay, because you are targeting only part of website that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I am using this `.gv-container-2777` so that it doesn't effect the whole website (only that part of the website)

Comment: Any word on above question ?

Comment: This is link to the same question?

Comment: That’s a different question. I am wondering if you can give me pointer how to solve that. I can’t make any changes in the HTML code. The only changes which I can do is CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181036/discussion-between-john-and-andrzej-gorgon).